# Mac terminal strange output on return

Tags: macos, terminal

Using the Mac terminal whenever I hit enter, regardless of shell it outputs the line with square brackets. The issue doesn't occur in iTerm2.

```
Dan@Mac ~                                                            [10:32:55] 
[> $                                                                            ]

Dan@Mac ~                                                            [10:36:11] 
[> $                                                                            ]

Dan@Mac ~                                                            [10:36:11] 
> $
```

So above is what there term looks like, input goes at > $ however on enter it shows with [> $.

Any advice appreciated, let me know if you need any other details.

edit: To clarify as this was marked duplicate of another thread which asks the functionality/purpose of mark, when posting this I did not know what mark was or that it existed.

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason, in the terminals settings under edit there is an option called mark.

Seems this is designed to mark the prompt line, once disabled this behaviour stops.